# Issue regarding overlapping features in Auto Cad

Tags: autocad

In AutoCAD 3D 2010 is there any command which allows user to point out overlapping features.

eg. if my text is overlapping with a line or polyline how will I point it out.

PS: I know about the `OVERKILL` command which allows users to delete overlapping features but I need to recognize such features instead of removing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For overlapping texts objects you can use [TSPACEINVADERS](http://www.acadclass.com/111/how-to-spot-overlapping-texts) command in AutoCAD 2016 (I cannot guarantee it exists in older releases).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Patrick tspaceinvaders command solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with closed regions (polylines) or even the extents of text entities, you can create regions and do a boolean intersection.  If there is a returned result, you have overlapping entities.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the problem which I am facing is that my text entities are overlapping on polylines so what I need to know is that how to point out such TEXTS, if I do a boolean intersection it creates a new region where my regions are intersecting but that is not my problem I simply want to figure those texts which are overlapping on my lines